# Keeping laravel command always running

Tags: laravel, redis, supervisord

I wrote a command for Laravel inside App\Console. My goal in creating this command is to subscribe to channel Redis and work according to the commands I receive.

```
class RedisListener extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'redis:listen';
 
    protected $description = 'Listen for events on redis channel';
 
    CONST ExternalChannel = "RedisPrefixMainMicroServiceChannel" ;
    CONST InternalChannel = "MainMicroServiceChannel" ;
 
    public function handle()
    {
        Redis::subscribe([self::InternalChannel],function ( $message ){
            /// TODO 
        });
    }
 
}
```

And I run this command with the supervisor, and everything goes well.

```
[program:microRedis]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/html/api/laravel/artisan redis:listen
user=octane
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/var/log/redis.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1024
```

But I found a problem. This command that I put in the supervisor will be terminated after a minute, or let's consider an error in the application. This command will terminate when autostart = true. It wants to raise this command again for about a second. It takes time to subscribe again to channel Redis. Do you have any ideas for me to cover this for a second?

Comment: Maybe you can use nodejs for it. Php is not suitable this type of thing

Answer (score 0):

i found the issue ,
in /config/database.php command is a 'redis.default' config
i duplicated config and addedd 'read_write_timeout' => 0 it means connection should not be terminated after client didnt recieved any message on subscription

/config/database.php

```
'redis-permanent-connection' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
            'read_write_timeout' => 0 , // default is 60s in laravel 9
        ],
```

```
 Redis::connection("redis-permanent-connection")->subscribe(["channel"],function ( $message ){
            /// TODO 
        }) ;
```